# What functions cannot be decorated in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, decorator

In a college test or interview question setting, how could you answer:

> What functions can't be decorated in Python?

It's beneficial to demonstrate depth of knowledge, so I would begin by briefly describing the uses of decorators in Python. What are their limitations?

I've read the [Decorator pattern Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and can't find any anti-patterns.

#### A. Decorator uses

1. Decorators in Python are useful to extend the functionality of module functions, class methods, and classes themselves. For example, using a debug logging wrapper to a function or a dynamic programming cache:

```py
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128)
def fibonacci(n=10):
    ...
```

2. A class can also act as a decorator (if you implement the `__init__()` and `__call__()` methods).
3. A decorator can be wrapped to allow passing of arguments. It can also be chained with other decorators.

#### B. When can't you use a decorator

1. You cannot use a decorator for variable assignments, calling functions etc. They are only used when defining a function/class/method.
2. You may not want to use a decorator on a recursive function as it effectively halves the maximum recursion depth (as suggested by @jasonharper).

**Are there any other cases when a decorator couldn't (*or shouldn't*) be used?**

Comment: If you decorate a recursive function, you effectively cut the maximum recursion depth in half.  And a function could possibly determine that it was decorated (by using the `inspect` module to look at the call stack, most likely), if it wanted to prohibit that for some reason.

Comment: @jasonharper that's a great point! thank you.

Comment: Would be grateful for a reopen: I've added an example situation, improved clarity of the question, and changed the formatting. This question aids general understanding of decorators in Python, shows research, and meets a need for lacking results when the question is Googled.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't decorate a lambda function. Also, a generator expression like `(x for x in foo)` technically defines a function, and you can't decorate that either.

Comment: @kaya3 good suggestion! It *is* possible decorate a lambda but you're correct in that you can't use the `@decorator` syntax. You'd have to define the lambda `f` and then wrap it with `f = decorator(f)`. Good point on the generator expression too, thanks :)

Comment: What is your actual question? Which functions *cannot* be decorated? Which functions *should not* be decorated? Note that strictly speaking, one doesn't decorate functions at all; one decorates ``class`` and ``def`` *statements*.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I got it wrong, but if you are not using syntactic sugar of the decorator ("@my_decorator"), then it's used via assigning a decorated function to a function you would like to decorate. So technically speaking, decorator can be used in assigning, not only in function definition, but function assigning to the other function:

```
# let's create a simple decorator
def mydecorator(decorated_func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Something happened in decorator!")
        return decorated_func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


# let's use decorator with syntactic sugar "@"
@mydecorator
def myfunc(myarg):
    print("my function", myarg)


# just simple function
def mysecond_func(myarg):
    print("my second function", myarg)

# let's decorate the second function with the same decorator,
# but without using syntactic sugar;
# it's identical with the first example with "@"
mysecond_func = mydecorator(mysecond_func)
```